# $G/H$ cyclic and $H$ subgroup of $Z(G)$, then $G$ cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

Gallian, in his Contemporary Abstract Algebra, first proves this theorem:

> **Theorem**: Let $G$ be a group and let $Z(G)$ be the center of $G$. If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is Abelian.
>
> **Proof:** Let $G/Z(G)=\langle gZ(G)\rangle$ and let $a\in G$. Then there exists an integer $i$ such that $aZ(G) =  (gZ(G))^i= g^ i Z(G)$. Thus, $a= g^ i z$ for some $z$ in $Z(G)$. Since both $g^ i$ and $z$ belong to $C(g)$, so does $a$. Because $a$ is an arbitrary element of $G$
> this means that every element of $G$ commutes with $g$ so $g \in Z(G)$. Thus, $gZ(G) = Z(G)$ is the only element of $G/Z(G)$.

Then the author goes on to say that: our proof shows that a better result is possible: If $G/H$ is cyclic, where $H$ is a subgroup of
$Z(G)$, then $G$ is Abelian.

So, I follow the same proof to prove this new statement. Everything goes fine for the first three sentences, when I replace $Z(G)$ with $H$ in above proof, but, I can't see how to deduce here $g\in Z(G)$ that $G$ indeed abelian.

Comment: For reference: The theorem above is Theorem 9.3 of the Eighth Edition.

Comment: No, I don't see it either. Good question!

Comment: $G / Z(G) \cong (G / H) / (Z(G) / H)$, so if $G / H$ is cyclic, then so is $G / Z(G)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G/H$ is cyclic then also $G/Z(G)$ is it because
$$
aH=bH\Rightarrow b^{-1}a\in H\leq Z(G)\Rightarrow aZ(G)=bZ(G)
$$
then $G/H=\langle gH\rangle\Rightarrow G/Z(G)=\langle gZ(G)\rangle$

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? I'm a beginner in group theory.

Comment: @JohnMars Suppose that $G/H=\langle aH\rangle$ (in other words $aH$ generates $G/H$) where $H\leq Z(G)$. Then for every $g\in G$ exists $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ such that $gH=(aH)^n=a^nH$ so $g^{-1}a^n\in H$ and so $g^{-1}a^n\in Z(G)$. This means also that $gZ(G)=[aZ(G)]^n$ so $aZ(G)$ is a generator of $G/Z(G)$.

Comment: So $G/H$ cyclic $\Rightarrow G/Z(G)$ cyclic $\Rightarrow G$ Abelian.